# How is Solomon's Wisdom acquired?

Tags: magi

In Magi, Aladdin is the only one who seems to be able to use 'Solomon's Wisdom', a power he obtained from Ugo in a dream.

My question is, how is Solomon's Wisdom acquired? Does it have anything to do with Ugo and why can't other Magi's such as Scheherazade tap into this power?

It only makes sense that they should be able to use it since they are Magi's and are favoured by the Rukh. I am sure it was not addressed in the anime since I only follow the anime (not the manga) but if it was revealed in the mangas then that is perfectly fine too.

Answer (score 3):

Had to delete my old post based on new reveals in the Alma Torren Arc.

He's Soloman's son so it was probably his inheritance/something that is passed down genetically as only Soloman had the ability before.

Solomon's wisdom is defined in the wikia as:

> This power allows normal people to hear the will of Rukh. This power
>   seems to be able to see the past, present and future, through the use
>   of Rukh. Aladdin was able to show Judar his past, causing him to freak
>   out. This power also is able to temporarily summon departed souls back
>   to life as a way to say any last goodbyes. This, however, is very
>   tiring to Aladdin. It allowed Aladdin to enter the body of Alibaba to
>   get rid of a curse cast on him by Ithnan. According to Ithnan this
>   power makes the person "Omniscient".